# Proving finite-stabilizers of a tensor group action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group with subgroup $H$ of finite index. Let $X$ be a $G$-set, (ie. G acts on $X$), then we can define the tensor $G$-set $$G \otimes_H X := (G \times X) / \simeq $$ where the equivalence relation is defined as $(gh,x) \simeq (g,hx)$ for all $g \in G, h \in H, x \in X$. There is a $G$-action on this set: $$ g' (g, x) := (g'g, x)$$

I am trying to verify the following statement: if $X$ has finite $G$-stabilizers, then so does $G\otimes_H X$. Here is what I've done so far:

Suppose for contradiction that $(g, x) \in G \otimes_H X$ has infinitely many $G$-stabilizers. Since $H \subset G$ is of finite index, we can choose some finite transversal $\left \{ s_1, s_2, ... , s_n \right \} \subset G$, so that for any $g \in G$, there exists some $s_k$ and $h \in H$ such that $g = s_k h$. Since the cosets partition $G$, then each $G$-stabilizer of $(g, x)$ lies in some coset $s_j H$. Furthermore, since there are finitely many cosets and infinitely many $G$-stabilizers, then there must be some $j \leq n$ such that there are infinitely many $G$-stabilizers in the coset $s_jH$. So we have $g_1, g_2, g_3, ... \in s_jH$ such that $(g_i g, x) \simeq (g, x) $. Furthermore. we can express $g = s_k h$ so that these equivalences become: $ (g_i s_k, hx) \simeq (g_i s_k h, x) \simeq (s_k h, x) \simeq (s_k, hx) $, so replacing $x$ by $hx$, we can make the following statement:

There exists $s_j$ and $s_k$ in the transversal such that there exists $g_1, g_2, g_3, ... \in s_j H$ and $(g_i s_k, x) \simeq (s_k, x)  \hspace{4pt} \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$

Or equivalently:

there exists $s_j$ and $s_k$ in the transversal such that there exists a sequence $h_1, h_2, h_3, ... \in H$ with $$(s_j h_1 s_k, x) \simeq  (s_j h_2 s_k, x) \simeq (s_j h_3 s_k, x) \simeq ...  \simeq (s_k, x)$$

Because $s_k$ can only be expressed as a product of elements in $G$ and $H$ in the trivial way (ie. $s_k = s_k * 1$), it seems as though these elements $ (s_k, x)$ are in some sense $\textit{irreducible}$, and this seems like it could offer up some sort of contradiction, but I'm not really sure how to conclude. Does this look like the right approach in the first place? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unclear to me why $X$ starts off as a full $G$-set if you're only using the $H$-action when constructing $G\times_H X$. Also unclear to me what the phrase "has finite $G$-stabilizers" means. Do you mean there are finitely many subgroups which are the stabilizer of an element of $G\times_H X$? Or that all stabilizers are finite? Also, just because the left cosets of $H$ partition $G$ doesn't mean every subgroup is contained in any of them - a subgroup can (and often must) intersect many of them nontrivially, and certainly can't be a subset of a coset that doesn't contain the identity element!

Comment: This is a right approach. What help do you need?

Comment: @runway44 i mean that for all $x \in X$, we have that $gx =x$ for only finitely many $g \in G$. When i say $G$-stabilizers, i am referring to elements $g \in G$ which stabilize $(g,x) \in G \otimes_H X$, so indeed, assuming our hypothesis, we can find a coset which contains infinitely many of these stabilizers.

Comment: I've only ever heard "stabilizer" to refer to subgroups, not elements.

Comment: @JCAA I'm not quite sure how to conclude. Am I correct to say that: $(g_i s_k, x) \simeq (s_k, x) $ implies that $g_i s_k = s_k $ ?

Comment: You need, I suppose, to prove that every pair in the tensor product has a finite stabilizer. You have established that every pair up to equivalence  has the form $(s_i, x)$. Now suppose that this point has infinite stabilizer.

Comment: I have added an answer. If it is not clear enough, you can ask. I will clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prove that every pair in the tensor product has a finite stabilizer. You have established that every pair up to equivalence has the form $(s_i, x)$. Now suppose that this point has infinite stabilizer $g_1,g_2,...$ Since there are only finitely many cosets  we can assume that all $g_k$ are in the same coset $s_jH$, $g_k=s_jh_k$, $k=1,2,...$. then $g_k(s_i,  x)=(s_j h_ks_i, x)=(s_is_m, h_k'x)=(s_i,hh_k'x)$ where $h_ks_i=s_mh_k'$ (again we can assume the same $m$ for all $k$) and $s_js_m=s_ih$ for some $h\in H$.  But this means that $hh_k'$ stabilizes $x$ in $X$ for all $k$. Since the stabilizer of $x$ is finite, we have many equalities $h_k'=h_l'$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I am slightly confused by the fact that you have the equivalence $(s_j h_k s_i, x) \simeq (s_j s_i, h_k x) $. From my understanding of the action on the tensor product, order matters when "quotienting" with the equivalence relation, ie that although $(gh, x) \simeq (g, hx)$, it is not necessarily the case that $(hg, x) \simeq (g, hx)$. Any intuitive idea why this can be done?

Comment: Furthermore, I don't quite see how we can ensure that $s_j s_i = s_i h$. Is conjugation of elements in transversal always in the subgroup? Or did we select $i$ such that this was true.

Comment: Indeed it requires clarification. I will fix the answer.

Comment: I have addressed  the first objection in the answer. The second one is not an error. You have that $g\cdot (s_i,x)\simeq (s_i,x)$ and it is clear that $(s_i,x)$ cannot be equivalent to any $(s_l,y)$ for $l\ne i$.